# Postgresql + Hibernate 5 column not found but coluimn exists

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I am converting my application to work with Postgresql and Hibernate 5 (used to be Mysql and Hibernate 4) but I run into a problem that has me baffled.

When I run my unit tests I get errors about missing columns, but the columns exist. The table name and column name in the error message are 100% equal to what's in the database.

Entity class snippet :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="bractiondata")
public class BusinessRuleActionData {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity=com.model.business.BusinessRule.class)
    @Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
    @JoinColumn(name = "businessRule")
    private BusinessRule businessRule;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private RuleActionEnum actionType;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="action", targetEntity=com.model.business.action.BusinessRuleActionDataTuple.class)
    @Cascade({CascadeType.ALL})
    @MapKey(name="fieldName")
    private Map<String, BusinessRuleActionDataTuple> tuples = new HashMap<String, BusinessRuleActionDataTuple>();

...methods
```

Error message :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in file [E:\business\projecten\yobu\yobu-model\bin\testContext-model-hibernate.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1076)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:851)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:128)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:954)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:884)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:338)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:373)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:362)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing column [actionType] in table [bractiondata]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.validateTable(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.performValidation(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.doValidation(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:458)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:881)
    ... 46 more
```

Postgresql create table statement :

```
CREATE TABLE public.bractiondata
(
  id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('bractiondata_id_seq'::regclass),
  "businessRule" bigint,
  "actionType" character varying(100),
  CONSTRAINT bractiondata_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT "bractiondata_businessRule_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("businessRule")
      REFERENCES public.businessrule (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

The table exists and apparently can be found. The column actionType exists too but for some reason cannot be found. Though I suspected correctly it would not make a difference I tried to add a @Column annotation to no effect. Does anyone know what the cause of this error in this situation can be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the mixed-case column names. Any SQL to select from them must put quotes around the names, and I don't know Hibernate but my guess would be that the quotes in your code are serving to enclose a string and not as actual quotes.

This is copied from a psql session:

```
create temporary table btest1
(id bigint,
"businessRule" bigint,
"actionType" character varying(100)
);

select id, businessRule, actionType from btest1;
ERROR:  column "businessrule" does not exist

select id, "businessRule", "actionType" from btest1;
 id | businessRule | actionType 
----+--------------+------------
(0 rows)
```

You can either figure out how to get double-quote characters into the SQL generated by Hibernate, or change your column names to use all lower-case.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I had a strong suspicion it was something like this. I tried renaming a few columns in one table to all lowercase and that made things work for that table. I think I'll rename those columns that need renaming, since that will make it easier to write queries when working with the db directly too, without quotes. .